# Need help completing a function for a Memory Card Game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a school poject which consists of making a Memory Card Game, and I'm having trouble creating a function which tells me when all the cards have been correctly flipped (and thus the game has ended).

This is what I have so far in my scripts.js :

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;
let allCardsFlipped = false;

function flipCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;

  this.classList.add('flip');

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;
    return;
  }

  secondCard = this;
  lockBoard = true;

  checkForMatch();
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.name === secondCard.dataset.name;
  isMatch ? disableCards() : unflipCards();
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);

  resetBoard();
}

function unflipCards() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
    secondCard.classList.remove('flip');

    resetBoard();
  }, 1500);
}

function resetBoard() {
  hasFlippedCard = false;
  lockBoard = false;
  firstCard = null;
  secondCard = null;
}

function haveAllCardBeenFlipped(){
  
  return allCardsFlipped = true
} 

function gameWon(){
  if (allCardsFlipped = true){
    window.location.href = 'vitoria.html'
  }
  else {
    break
  }
}

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let ramdomPos = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 12);
    card.style.order = ramdomPos;
  });
})();

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));
```

My question now is what do I write in the function haveAllCardsBeenFlipped so that it checks if the cards have been flipped and returns True if the condition has been met, otherwise breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate through all of the cards and check if all of them has `flip` class or not. That should give you your answer.

```
function haveAllCardBeenFlipped(){
  let allCardFlipped = true;

  cards.forEach(card => {
    if(card.classList.contains('flip')) {
      allCardFlipped = false;
      break;
    }
  });

  return allCardsFlipped;
}
```

Comment: This has been very helpful so thank you very much and I understood what you coded, but the problem I'm having now is that cards don't flip. Before I added the new functions, haveAllCardsBeenFlipped and gameWon they flipped fine, but now I click on them and nothing happens. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) array method to do this. You can create an array from the result of `querySelectorAll` with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```
function haveAllCardBeenFlipped(){
  return Array.from(cards).every(card => card.classList.contains('flip'));
}
```

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem with your answer as I had with the other answer on this post, which is when I had this function to the script the cards stop flipping, which is problematic, any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Hmm... sounds like a different question :). Most likely because the code depends on the `allCardsFlipped` global variable instead of calling `haveAllCardBeenFlipped()` when it needs to know if all cards have been flipped. I'd remove `allCardsFlipped` and replace it with `haveAllCardBeenFlipped()`.

Comment: I see, I kind of get what you mean, I'll try working on it by myself since I don't want to push your kindness. Thanks for the help though. Also, would it be fine if I make a new post on here asking this question, but with your answer included in the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course! You can include the code and include a link to the question for reference. Just make sure the new question stands on its own.